# DataWeaver Mule Document section 1.1.2 and 3.4 examples not working?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

Going through the Dataweaver documentaion 
 Link:https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave#_attribute_selector_expressions

Section 3.4  Key Present
Trying out the example provide  below .

```
Input:
       <users>
     <name>Mariano</name>
       <name>Luis</name>
        <name>Mariano</name>
  </users>
```

Transform:

```
        %dw 1.0
      %input payload application/xml   
      %output application/xml
       ---
       users: payload.users.name[?($ == "Mariano")]
```

when I try to give this expression in my DataWeaver it  gives warning like `cannot coerce a:string to a: array:(7,92)`.
Have given the same way mentioned in the document. Could anyone  please advice.

Expected Response:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <users>
          <name>Mariano</name>
          <name>Mariano</name>
          </users>
```

Also in the document 1.1.2 string manipulation example wasn't working for me

```
        %dw 1.0
        %input payload application/xml
        %output application/json
         %function words(name) name splitBy " "
         ---
       contacts: payload.users.*user map using (parts =  words($.name)){
        firstName: parts[0],
        (secondName: parts[1]) when (sizeOf parts) > 2,
        lastName: parts[-1],
        email: "$((lower $.name) replace " " with ".")@acme.com.ar",
      address: $.street
         }
```

showing error like `multiple marker at this line missing '}' no viable alternative at input email`

Started learning and working out the examples provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the docs has a typo, there is an `*` missing before `name` (it should be fixed):

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml
---
users: payload.users.*name[?($ == "Mariano")]
```

The problem is that XML doesn't have a built-in list representation, so the list is represented by multiple occurences of a tag. The expression `*name` returns a list with the occurrences of `name`, the expression `[?($ == "Mariano")]` it's like a filter (I prefer filter since it is easier to understand).

The cryptic error message appears because the operator applies to a list, but `payload.users.name` returns the first appeareance of `name`. (That's why it says cannot coerce string to array).

Comment: Thanks!! Have any clue about document 1.1.2 ?

Comment: I didn't understood the question, you mean what means each part on the example displayed in the section 1.1.2 of the docs?

Comment: Section 1.1.2 example provided in the document also not working for me.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer since 3.4  question is working fine.